# spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesi can not use @Output

Tags: amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-stream

first I have to describe my question and what I have done.
As aws cloud services is my chosen，the kinesis service is my first choice.
So,the spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis component is needed to build my application.

this is the channel interface:

```html
public interface KinesisChannel {
  String StockTradeStream = "StockTradeStream";
  String CHANNEL_SECOND = "channel_second";


  @Input(KinesisChannel.StockTradeStream)
  SubscribableChannel in_channel_a();

  @Input(KinesisChannel.CHANNEL_SECOND)
  SubscribableChannel in_channel_second();

//    @Output(KinesisChannel.CHANNEL_SECOND)
//    MessageChannel out_channel_second();

}
```

this is to cunsume the message and gives a return after sending message to another channel.

```html
@EnableRxJavaProcessor()
class App2{
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel StockTradeStream;

    @Bean
    public RxJavaProcessor<Object,Object> processor(){
        return inputStream -> inputStream.map(data->{
            logger.info("Received message:"+data);
            if(data!=null){
                StockTradeStream.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("send a StockTradeStream message!").build());
            }
            return data;
        }).buffer(5).map(data -> String.valueOf("From Output Channel Return -"+ data));
    }
}
```

when I start my application ,comes out the exception:

```html
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-01 11:31:22.288 ERROR 37048 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/provisioning/ProducerDestination;Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/ProducerProperties;)Lorg/springframework/messaging/MessageHandler;
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at com.bind.ApplicationStarter.main(ApplicationStarter.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/provisioning/ProducerDestination;Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/ProducerProperties;)Lorg/springframework/messaging/MessageHandler;
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:124) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:238) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
... 14 common frames omitted
```

after several tries，I found that output channel can't be bind with @Output，but sending message is ok by this way：

```html
        StockTradeStream.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("send a StockTradeStream message!").build());
```

and everything is ok if I replace kinesis with rabbit/kafka,with matched stream binder,which is started by docker locally.output channel can be used with @Output

so what's the problem,did I miss something leading to this problem？

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/provisioning/ProducerDestination;Lorg/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/ProducerProperties;)Lorg/springframework/messaging/MessageHandler;

It looks like you are trying to use it with the wrong version of Spring Cloud Stream. It requires 1.3.x. - see [the pom](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/pom.xml#L18).